# changing the class of an html element using javascript is unstable

Tags: javascript

I used this code to change the `class` of an html-element when an `onclick`-event occurs. The change occurs(i.e. the text color changes) but the change is not stable, it goes back to the styling of its previous `class`, and my javascript code doesn't seem to have any effect.

```
function submitrequest(){
    var x = document.forms["signupform"]["name"].value;
    if(x.toString().length <= 0){
        var y = document.getElementById("nametd");
        y.className = 'change';
    }
}
```

What should I do to make this effect permanent?

Comment: When does it go back to previous styling? After the form is submitted and the page reloads?

Comment: it goes immediately, it seems that the change takes place just like a blinking.... but it blinks for once.

Comment: That's odd. So the page does not reload? Here's an example without actually posting data: http://jsfiddle.net/uRnM9/

Comment: @showdev that works cool. thnx!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not have to define a click-handler to notice that a button of a form was clicked.
A form can have an submit-button:
      
and when this button is clicked an submit event is fired for the form.
Furthermore when an user do not clicks on the button and just presses enter then a submit-event is fired too. So you handle both situations automatically.

I suggest that you define you function that way:

```
  window.onload = function(){

    document.getElementById('signupform').addEventListener('submit',function(e){

      changeClassOfNametd();
      e.preventDefault(); // this prevents the side from being reloaded by the script.

    });

  };

  function changeClassOfNametd(){
      var nameValue = document.forms["signupform"]["name"].value;
      if(nameValue){ // when value is "" (zero, no signs) it is false anyway
          var y = document.getElementById("nametd");
          y.className = 'change';
          //y.classList.toggle('change'); you can toggle classname "change" too
          // which works that way class="unchange" -> class="unchange change"  
          // you have to define appropriate css-classes for toggle.
      }
  }
```

The Code above works whereever you put it into your html-file.

Answer (score -1):

By the name of the function it is called on a form submission.

Because the form submits and it goes back to the original that was set when the new page loads.

If you want to maintain that, you would have to apply the class on the next page load. Most developers will do that with the serverside. If you do not actually want the form to submit, cancel it.

Comment: so what should i do to get rid of it?

Comment: @buet_baba If you want to style the form after the page is refreshed you'd need to persist a flag or style somewhere, either on the server, as a request parameter, on the browser, etc.